Nuclear (astro)physics for relativists and field theorists
Lately I've become interested in compact stars and I would like to learn a bit about the nuclear physics that goes into them. However, I don't know anything about nuclear physics, except for a few terms I learned through SciComm (liquid drop model, magic numbers). I am, however, experienced with graduate quantum mechanics, quantum field theory, and general relativity. Hence, I would like to know suggestions of references on nuclear physics that could be interesting to field theorists and relativists. Ideally, I would like something that discusses the liquid drop model and magic numbers, but the main goal would be to understand compact stars a bit better.

The standard reference I was referred to, was Krane.

The fourth chapter of N. K. Glendenning's Compact Stars is an introduction into relativistic nuclear field theory in the context of neutron stars. It is an older book but I think it is still a very good reference for the physics of isolated neutron stars.
